# How do i generate a dll file for Selfie Segmentation Mediapipe

Tags: c++, mediapipe, segmentationselfie

How do i go about generating a dll file for Selfie Segmentation [Mediapipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/selfie_segmentation.html). I just couldn't figure it out since there is no source code specifically for Selfie Segmentation part, do i need to call my own functions? or is there any other way doing this.

I referred to this example for generating a dll for [face mesh](https://github.com/maletsden/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_mesh_dll) using windows_dll_library function. Is this how I should approach?